# How can I get flyspell to ignore TeX codes in MathJax?

Tags: emacs, latex, mathjax, dot-emacs, flyspell

So, in emacs auctex mode, it is easy to have flyspell ignore TeX math codes by adding a couple of lines to one's .emacs (or other initialization) file. At the moment I'm working on a long HTML document that contains a ton of embedded TeX code, which is being rendered by MathJax. Since it's an HTML file, I'm using nxml mode to write it (mostly to get nice syntax coloring and nice formatting). But since I'm not in auctex (or other LaTeX) mode, flyspell sees all the TeX math codes as misspellings. Is there a way to get flyspell to ignore them the way it does in auctex mode? Thanks.

Comment: Please update the question text to provide the specific details of those "couple of lines" which fix this for auctex.  Presumably the solution would be similar, and those details will point to how that was implemented.